# perform multiple MySQL queries with one web service iOS

Tags: php, mysql, ios, web-services

I am new to the iOS development side of things and even newer to the development of APIs and WebServices.

Im having trouble with having my iOS app connect to a web service and then list all files related specifically to the user.

The problem I am having results mainly form the fact that the user data is related via 3 different tables. For example: 'ID' field in users table relates to 'customer' field in properties table which then relates to 'visible' field in the reports table. So essentially I need to run a query that takes the $_SESSION variables from my web service login script (Already created and working) and performs the queries I need to get the list of reports so I can populate a UITableView in my iOS app.

NOW……….Thats where I fall down. I actually don't have a clue what the best way to do this is. Can this be done in a single script and still have the results encoded as JSON and returned to the API? Or does there have to be multiple calls from the API once each data set is received?

Can you point me to any tutorials or info relating to this type of structure?

Obviously I am happy to do the reading and learn these techniques for myself, but I have been looking for 2 days and I haven't found what i need.

any help would be great.

**---------------
ADDITIONAL INFO
---------------**

ok so I read up on SQL JOINS and I have come with half of my issue fixed using the following query:

```
$sql=( "SELECT properties.title, reports.title, reports.date, reports.link FROM reports JOIN properties ON reports.visible = properties.customer WHERE properties.customer ='".$customerid."'" );
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
```

this allowed me to show the data i need by customer and it works great. Now how do I query it by building? Do I have to write an additional query?  or am I just not seeing they way i am supposed to be using this function properly??

Answer (score 0):

If I get you right, that's what you need:

Interaction between iOs and ServerSide using calls to API and exchanging JSON data (usually).
You need to make some "endpoints" in your api that will serve data.

For example, if you want to get customers, than send GET request from iOs to site.com/api/v1/customers.
If you want to get some reports, you can POST data to site.com/api/v1/reports in JSON format.

Comment: That all makes sense, however, there is nothing in the customers table that has the details of reports and similarly there is nothing in the reports table that relates specifically to the user. So what I need is a way to have the user login encode POST data back to the Webservice i.e. ID, Name etc then use that data to query properties table to get more POST data i.e. 'building name' 'customer' AND THEN use that data to query the reports table.

Comment: Read up on SQL joins. Query for the data, return it to the app. You might be making this harder than it needs to be.

Comment: beautiful thanks for the tip. When you say I may be making this harder than it needs to be, can you elaborate?